# Least value concurrent map

Tags: java, guava, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I require an implementation of a map, 
that supports concurrency, and only stores the least/most value added (depending on the comparator).
Would the following code work?

```
 class LeastValConcurrentMap<K, V> {

  //put the least value
  private final Comparator<V> comparator;
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();

  LeastValConcurrentMap(Comparator comparator) {
     this.comparator = comparator;
  }

  public void put(K k, V v)  {
     V vOld = map.put(k, v);
     if (vOld == null || comparator.compare(v, vOld) <= 0) //i.e. v <= vOld so better
        return;
     //recursively call self
     put(k, vOld);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
     return map.toString();
  }
}
```

Can you please give me an example of where/why it wouldn't work?
Is there something in the guava or standard java library I could use?

Comment: I believe, that you want     V vOld = map.get(k, v);

Comment: you need to synchronize LeastValConcurrentMap<K,V>.put(K k, V v) method, because the ConcurrentHashMap may be thread safe, but your method is not.

Comment: You have a race condition.  Consider what happens when two threads are putting the same key at the same time. i.e. they are both running put()

Comment: that is where the recursive method comes, to call itself again and check that v is still the least value

Comment: assume key:val , concurrentMap contains k1:3, thread1 puts val k1:2, vOld = 3 returns, thread2 puts k1:1, (put is atomic, in my understanding), vOld = 2 returns...

Comment: please note my class doesn't implement map...I may have phrased the question incorrectly, I need the least value to be stored in a concurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more complex, you need to use atomic `ConcurrentHashMap.replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue)`

```
public void put(K k, V v) {
    V oldValue = map.putIfAbsent(k, v);
    if (oldValue == null) {
        // this is the first mapping to this key 
        return;
    }
    for (;;) {
        if (comparator.compare(v, oldValue) <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        // this replace returns true only if oldValue was replaced with new value atomically   
        if (map.replace(k, oldValue, v)) {
            break;
        }
        // otherwise another attempt
        oldValue = map.get(k);
    }
```

Comment: looks good, I'm not sure about comparator line in your answer, should it not be comparator.compare(oldValue, v) <= 0 (old value is better, so break)

Comment: But I just took the one from your code :), sure, change according to the required logic

Comment: I don't know if you noted the recursion in my code? can you give me an example where mine wouldn't work

Comment: here - put(k, vOld); while you are putting it another thread interfered and already inserted a smaller value.

Comment: note that the logic seems complicated and it is. but it is the only way to make it lock-free

Comment: so that would call back into itself, call map.put() again, and get the better smaller val, then call itself a third time to put the the one from the other thread

Comment: you can take a look at how AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet is implemented, the idea is similar, and it also uses loop, trying until successful

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev just curious to know why synchronizing the method wouldn't work

Comment: @Dev Blanked I didnt say it wouldnt :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to synchronize the put method of LeastValConcurrentMap class. It seems you are only putting values into the map.. where/how would these values be used. To ensure concurrent access you need to think about both read/write operations. Also the last line of your put method should be like map.put(k, vOld)

Comment: please note my method is recursive

Comment: could you please explain why it needs to be recursive

Comment: it needs to check again, in case another thread put a lower value into it

Comment: that's why you need to synchronize your put method. In that way until one thread leaves the method another won't come into the method. When you do a recursive call and try to put the lower value back into the map there is a chance the map is read by others before you put it back again...and in that case it would have the wrong values

Comment: If you have to use the `synchronized` construct in conjunction with a `Concurrent*` container, chances are you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga you're correct probably can use a normal hash map and not expose it directly to outside. Methods that read/write to this can be on LeastValConcurrentMap being properly synchronized. But it doesn't take away the need to synchronize the 'put' method :-)